# How can i sent mail using PhpMailer in 000webhost but it working in before Hosting?

Tags: php, phpmailer, web-hosting

**Error/SMTP Debug**

> I am using free Hosting

> These are the errors shown in the SMTP debug,
> I tried all the error rectifying method

```
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO pro-online-grocery-store.000webhostapp.com
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO pro-online-grocery-store.000webhostapp.com
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-06-09 10:48:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-06-09 10:48:29 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu534-5.7.14 r9miUOgrMuntYtRkI3wx89ZiLPDiYDroneH6_Ac89byfZeSU2gtMewvVSN-TnwnTEsK2X534-5.7.14 X6W1XKlpqvOKd-K2MZpowZc693zGaaoSyXDK15XQ5QE-ox79_jKysPinbpuBFaXB>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 v17sm12296941qta.77 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2021-06-09 10:48:29 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/353/16879353/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php:278) in /storage/ssd3/353/16879353/public_html/function_db.php on line 36
```

**My PhpMailer code**

> I think my code is correct because it works perfectly in local host and dont know why it is not working

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function mailTo($to, $user, $subject, $body, $success, $error)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = '***************@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '*********';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('saigrocery@gmail.com', 'onlineshopping');
        $mail->addAddress($to, $user);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        
        if ($mail->send()) {
            header($success);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        header($error);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can u try ssl port 465 , i say because i use this , also in gmail u need to manually enable login on third party apps I believe

Comment: still not working, I am enable third party apps, remove two step verification and change tls to ssl and their port then also not working